# Clarification on CVE-2022-29117 .NET Denial of Service Vulnerability

Tags: .net, security

This article:

[.Net Denial of Service Vulnerability - CVE-2022-29117](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3rq8-h3gj-r5c6)

suggests that only applications using .NET 6, .NET 5 or .NET Core 3.1 are impacted.

Are .NET Framework applications (from 4.6.2 to 4.8) impacted if the vulnerable assembly versions mentioned in the advisory are referenced?

Comment: There are no other supported .NET Core versions. Older versions (1.x, 2.x) have reached end-of-life which means they don't even get security patches. .NET (Core) 5 is also out of support but many companies haven't migrated to .NET 6, the current long term support version.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated the question, as I wanted to specifically ask about .NET Framework applications.

Comment: The link is about .NET Core, not .NET Framework. These are two completely different runtimes and SDKs. .NET 5 and 6 are .NET *Core* 5 and 6. The word `Core` was dropped for marketing reasons

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I received a notification from GitHub for my personal repos on .NET Framework, suggesting that my repos 'might be' impacted by this vulnerability. Thus, I think the answer to the question I raised above is 'Yes', but I just wanted it confirmed because of the slightly ambiguous 'might be' in the notification. I was particularly referring to the use of earlier versions of Microsoft.Owin and Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies assemblies.

Comment: Those assemblies aren't specific to .NET Core. If they're vulnerable you need to upgrade them. Which you should do anyway. The 4.2.2 versions came out 4 months ago

Answer (score 0):

I raised a support ticket with Microsoft's .NET team about this. They suggested to install a security update as a solution:

[CVE-2022-30130 - Security Update Guide - Microsoft - .NET Framework Denial of Service Vulnerability targeting .NET Framework](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2022-30130).